# How to call function in lua synchronously?

Tags: typescript, lua, neovim

I would like to run some of the `typescript.nvim` actions command successively how should I do it? for now I have this

```lua
 local ts = require("typescript")
 vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
    group = augroupTS,
    buffer = bufnr,
    callback = function()
        ts.actions.addMissingImports({ sync = true })
        ts.actions.removeUnused({ sync = true })
        ts.actions.fixAll({ sync = true })
        ts.actions.organizeImports({ sync = true })
    end,
 })
```

This gives me inconsistent output, sometimes the `removeUnused` or `addMisingImports` is not executed, I need to resave the files several times should that I will get the expected output